# Why does not $grandtotal show correctly?

Tags: php

Let's say $_SESSION['totalprice'] is 1200.
However  echo $totalprice; outputs 1200 and echo $grandtotal; outputs 66. Grandtotal should be 1265.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$totalprice = $_SESSION['totalprice'];
$shipping= 65;

if (count($_SESSION['cart'])){
 $count = 1;
 foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $PID => $row){ 
  echo "<p class='padnmgn'><b>". $row['count'] . " " . $row['name'] . " @ " . $row['price']."</b></p><br/>\n";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_".$count."' value='".$row['name']."'/>\n";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_quantity_".$count."' value='".$row['count']."'/>\n";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_price_".$count."' value='".$row['price']."'/>\n";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_currency_".$count."' value='NOK'/>\n";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='ship_method_name_".$count."' value='Posten'/>\n";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='ship_method_price_".$count."' value='65.00'/>\n";

 }
}
$grandtotal = $totalprice + $shipping;

echo $totalprice;
echo $grandtotal;
```

Comment: As a side note; you probably want to do `$count++` at the end of the foreach loop, otherwise all your items have the same `$count`.

Comment: First rule: simplify. What happens if you comment out all unnecessary code (everything inside the *if*). Please also post it that way, as now you're including a bunch of code that has nothing to do with your problem, but it still takes us some minutes to get that.

Comment: Next, try `var_dump()` instead of `echo`, it gives you the datatype as well as the value, so if the problem really is that there are some decimal parts to your variables as Safraz Ahmed implies, you'll spot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$grandtotal = ((int) $totalprice) + $shipping;
```

Comment: @shin: then most likely your values of total gets changed in the session by some code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the value inside `$totalprice` is actually an integer and are you sure it's not being modified before you get to the addition? Try doing `var_dump($totalprice);` just before you do the addition, to see what value it really has at that point.

If it does have the value you expect, then you may need to cast it to an integer explicitly for the calculation to work properly, so something like `(int)$totalprice + $shipping;` etc.

For example,

```
<?php
    $totalprice = "1200blahblah";
    $shipping = 65;
    $grandtotal = (int)$totalprice + $shipping;
    echo $grandtotal; // still prints "1265"
?>
```

Comment: It shows as string: string(8) "1,072.00". However if I use $newtotalprice = (int)$totalprice;
var_dump($newtotalprice); It shows int(1), nothing else.

Comment: The output is 1,(comma)072.(dot)00. Is it the cause of problem?

Comment: Yes, that is your problem. PHP is trying to convert the string to an integer, and so it's just taking the "1" before it hits the "," character (since it can't convert "," to a number). Which is why it's doing 65+1=66. You need to remove the formatting from the string so that it's just the numbers you want. This will remove the "," characters: $totalprice = str_replace(',','',$totalprice); Then (int)$totalprice will give you the right value.

Comment: Although since you're dealing with prices, you probably want to work with floats and not ints. Also you probably shouldn't be formatting the number until you're ready to output it, otherwise it makes doing calculations more prone to errors, just like you were getting.